# How can I make each rest endpoint read a cookie and use that value in okhttp Interceptor?

Tags: rest, kotlin, retrofit, dropwizard, okhttp

I have lots of endpoints like:

@GET
  index()

@GET
  @Path("/{id}")

and by adding:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/{id}")
  fun getThing(@CookieParam("My-Cookie") cookie: String?)
```

I can read the value in that cookie just fine.

But I don't want to add this `@CookieParam("My-Cookie") cookie: String?` line to 100's of endpoints. I want to somehow make this happen for each one by default and then use that value when I make an http call to another API using okhttp retrofit.

Comment: you should write an [interceptor/adapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters) for the retrofit to sets up cookie automatically.

Comment: all the examples I see for this don't give me access to that same cookies I have from @CookieParam("My-Cookie"). Do you have link?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an interceptor to add cookies for you. Interceptor are quite flexible, you can have an interceptor for received cookies and another to set your cookies.

```
var cookie: String? = null

fun createOwnClient(): MyOwnClient {
    val client = createOkHttpClient()
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(MyOwnConstants.API_BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .build()
    return retrofit.create(MyOwnClient::class.java)
}

fun createOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val addCookiesInterceptor = createAddCookiesInterceptor()
    val receivedCookiesInterceptor = createReceivedCookiesInterceptor()
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(addCookiesInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(receivedCookiesInterceptor)
            .build()
}

fun createAddCookiesInterceptor(): Interceptor {
    return Interceptor {
        val requestBuilder = it.request().newBuilder()
        if (cookie != null) {
            requestBuilder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie)
        }
        it.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
    }
}

fun createReceivedCookiesInterceptor(): Interceptor {
    return Interceptor {
        val originalRequest = it.proceed(it.request())
        cookie = originalRequest.header("Set-Cookie")
        originalRequest
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend rolling your own Cookie Interceptor like @natan Suggested. OkHttp has built in functionality for cookie jars that will handle much more than just the basics. For example if you need expirations, domain based, path based, ssl only...

```
import okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar;

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
JavaNetCookieJar cookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cookieJar(cookieJar).build();
```

This should handle all of the cookies for you by adding one extra OkHttp module.